# How can I make a complex/long running SQL query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have created a query that retrieves data from multiple tables. When I run it, it takes ~200 seconds to execute. I am now trying to make the query more efficient, but I am reaching my limits and cannot find a solution. Do you maybe have an idea how I could improve the following query?

```sql
SELECT s1.otherdeed_id, s1.timestamp_start, s1.listingprice, s1.listing_currency, otherdeed_index.category, otherdeed_index.koda_id, kodas.mega, otherdeed_index.artifact_name, otherdeed_index.sediment
FROM otherdeed_opensea_listings s1
JOIN (
  SELECT otherdeed_id, listingprice, MAX(timestamp_start) AS timestamp_start
  FROM otherdeed_opensea_listings
  GROUP BY otherdeed_id) AS s2
  ON s1.otherdeed_id = s2.otherdeed_id AND s1.timestamp_start = s2.timestamp_start
INNER JOIN otherdeed_index ON otherdeed_index.id_otherdeed = s1.otherdeed_id 
INNER JOIN kodas ON otherdeed_index.koda_id = kodas.kodaname
ORDER BY otherdeed_id;
```

The query should deliver a list of the latest listing prices of the ***otherdeed_opensea_listings*** table (16k entries) and connect it with the tables ***otherdeed_index*** (100k entries) and ***kodas*** (10k entries) to get some relevant data to analyze.

I grouped the ***otherdeed_opensea_listings*** table to get only one result for each ***otherdeedid***, moreover it was also relevant to get only the latest results with the highest ***timestamp_start*** value.

Below you can see my sql structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `kodas` (
 `kodaid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `kodaname` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `mega` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `clothing` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `core` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `eyes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `head` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `weapon` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`kodaid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `otherdeed_index` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_otherdeed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `plot` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `sediment` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `sediment_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `environment` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `environment_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `artifact_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `r_east` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `r_west` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `r_south` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `r_north` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `r_east_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `r_west_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `r_south_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `r_north_tier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `koda_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `otherdeed_opensea_listings` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `eventid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `event_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `auction_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `otherdeed_id` int(9) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp_end` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `duration_active` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `listingprice` float NOT NULL,
 `listing_currency` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418927 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The output of my sql query: (explain select)
[image]

Comment: From my personal experience. I think, its time to implement simple caching. or disk cache the sql query results in json file and loop it. you can see huge performance difference (Even at high traffic because those queries are cached in server side too) ;)

Comment: Please update your question to show the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query and the indices that exist on these tables

Comment: @NickW I have updated the description, I hope this helps :)

Comment: @AjmalPraveen Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not an expert in this field and would like to have a simple solution with SQL :D, I really just want to analyze data, with this query that will be stored later in an auxiliary table.

Comment: have you defined any indexes on your tables?  If not you should.  If you have you need to show them

Comment: Hello @Hogan , what do you exactly mean with Indexes? :/ are those simple primary keys?

Comment: @Frostyz -- all sql systems allow you to define indexes in addition to the "default" of the primary key.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm#:~:text=Advertisements,ordering%20of%20access%20to%20records.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables used in your query and output of `explain select ...rest of your select`

Comment: Hello @ysth i have made the updates! Thank you

Comment: @Frostyz :) Okay, so you will need indexes on WHERE id's and Add any caching layer such as memcached or mysql proxy, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need some indexes. Try adding the following:

```
ALTER TABLE otherdeed_opensea_listings 
ADD INDEX timestamp_start (timestamp_start),
ADD INDEX otherdeed_id (otherdeed_id);

ALTER TABLE otherdeed_index 
ADD INDEX id_otherdeed (id_otherdeed),
ADD INDEX koda_id (koda_id);

ALTER TABLE kodas 
ADD INDEX kodaname (kodaname);
```

That would probably give you quicker results. Here's a [fiddle test with explain](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a4c725c2b152088a3bd8232527e91e2).